# Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for "xxx". NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, static-site, ssg

I am getting this error `"Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for 'xxx'"` when I try to create my page in NextJS.

I don't want to generate any static page on build time. So why do I need to create a `'getStaticPaths'` function?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you are creating a dynamic page eg: `product/[slug].tsx` then even if you don't want to create any page on build time you need to create a `getStaticPaths` method to set the `fallback` property and let NextJS know what to do when the page you are trying to get doesn't exist.

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ slug: string }> = async () => {

    return {
        paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
        fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
    }
}
```

`getStaticPaths` does mainly two things:

- Indicate which paths should be created on build time (returning a `paths` array)
- Indicate what to do when a certain page eg: "product/myProduct123" doesn't exist in the NextJS Cache (returning a `fallback` type)

Comment: hi, i'm usign your code, en locally this works fine, but when I run "npm run build" and start de app "npm start", the page that have a dynamic path returns 500 in nextjs side. :C

Answer (score 18):

Dynamic Routing Next Js

pages/users/[id].js

```
import React from 'react'

const User = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body text-center">
            <h3>{user.name}</h3>
            <p>Email: {user.email} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const users = await res.json()

  const paths = users.map((user) => ({
    params: { id: user.id.toString() },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: false }
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${params.id}`)
  const user = await res.json()

  return { props: { user } }
}

export default User
```

Comment: but what do you do when you refresh the page and lose the id and it cannot fetch any data anymore?

Answer (score 8):

For rendering dynamic route use  `getServerSideProps()` instead of `getStaticProps()`

For Example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({
locale,
}: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<Record<string, unknown>>> {

return {
    props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale || 'de', ['common', 'employees'], nextI18nextConfig)),
    },
  }
}
```

[You can check here as well](https://onecompiler.com/questions/3w538e6dv/error-getstaticpaths-is-required-for-dynamic-ssg-pages-and-is-missing-for-topics-content)

Comment: false, as said by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves -  "Using getStaticProps is perfectly fine with dynamic routes, as long as getStaticPaths is also used. Using getServerSideProps will no longer statically generate the pages, and will use SSR instead."

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `getStaticPaths`, you are telling next.js that you want to pregenerate that page. However since you used it inside a dynamic page, next.js does not know in advance how many pages it has to create.

with `getStaticPaths`, we fetch the database. If we are rendering blogs, we fetch the database to decide how many blogs we have, what would be `idOfBlogPost` and then based on this information, `getStaticPath` will pre-generate pages.

also, `getStaticProps` does not run only during the build time. If you add `revalidate:numberOfSeconds`, next.js will recreate new page with fresh data after "numberOfSeconds" time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i try to use getStaticProps for my next.js project. this one worked for me.

```
   export default function componentName(props) {
return(
<div></div>
)

 export async function getStaticPaths(ctx) {
    
    
    
        return {
            paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
            fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
        }
    }

export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
//-----------api call ------------
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You're rendering a dynamic route so use getServerSideProps() instead of getStaticProps()

Comment: Using `getStaticProps` is perfectly fine with dynamic routes, as long as `getStaticPaths` is also used. Using `getServerSideProps` will no longer statically generate the pages, and will use  SSR instead.