# Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/blogs/[post]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, ssg

I try to `npm run build` .

> Build error occurred
> Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/blogs/[post]'.

my code:

```
function post (props){
   console.log(props);
   return(
       <div>
           test
       </div>
   )
}
export const getStaticProps = async(post)=>{
   const blogPost =  await axios({
       method: 'get',
       url: `api url=${post}`});

   return{
       props:{params:blogPost}
   }
}

export default withRouter(post);
```

Comment: Dynamic routes (in your case `/blogs/[post]`) that use `getStaticProps` require `getStaticPaths` to be defined. I'd recommend you have a read through [`getStaticPaths` docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for "xxx". NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783199/error-getstaticpaths-is-required-for-dynamic-ssg-pages-and-is-missing-for-xxx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation on [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation). You can find a good example there.

Your /blogs/[post] needs all the possible paths of your posts to know how many of them should next build. So in [post] you need to implement getStaticPaths that will fetch all slugs of your posts