# Create dynamic routes by id from Next JS pages api

Tags: javascript, async-await, graphql, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a page with a list of objects called `stories` that displays all my stories in an array. I also have a detail page with displays an **individual story**.

I want to click on a link on any given story on the list, then it will navigate me to the individual story. I want to use `_id` as my dynamic part of the URL, as shown in the GraphQL below.

**My Graphql**

```
export const listAllStories = () => {
  const query = gql`
    query StoryEntries($size: Int) {
      storyEntries(_size: $size) {
        data {
          _id
          _ts
          name
          premises{
            data{
              _id
              content
            }
          }
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  `

  return graphQLClient
      .request(query, { size: 999 })
      .then(({ storyEntries: { data } }) => data)
}
```

**IN MY PAGES API I HAVE**

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const handlers = {
    GET: async () => {
      const storyEntries = await listAllStories()
      res.json(storyEntries)
    },
  }

  if (!handlers[req.method]) {
    return res.status(405).end()
  }

  await handlers[req.method]()
}
```

**ON THE STORY LIST PAGE I HAVE**

```
const ENTRIES_PATH = '/api/entries/allStories'

const useEntriesFlow = ({ initialEntries }) => {
    const { data: entries } = useSWR(ENTRIES_PATH, {
        initialData: initialEntries,
    })

    const EntryItem = ({ entry }) => (
         <>
            {entries?.map((entry) => (
                  {entry.name}
       <Link href="/story/[storyId]" as={`/story/${entry._id}`}>
                                <a>Go</a>
                            </Link>
             ))}
         </>
    )

export const getStaticProps = async () => ({
    props: {
        initialEntries: await listAllStories(),
    },
    revalidate: 1,
})
```

This is fine and works.

**AND THEN ON THE DETAIL PAGE FOR EACH INDIVIDUAL STORY `[storyId].js` I HAVE  **

```
export default function Story({story}) {

    const router = useRouter()
    const storyId = router.query.storyId
    return(
        <>
            <h5>hello {story._id}</h5>
        </>
    )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/`);
    const { data } = await res.json();
    const paths = data.map(story => {
        return {
            params: { id: story._id.toString() }
        }
          // trying to get the _id from each story 
    })
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

    export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const { storyId } = context.query;    // Your dynamic page is [storyId].js
    const server = "http://localhost:3000";

    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/${storyId}`);
    // trying to get the params._id from each story
    console.log(res)
    const { data } = await res.json();
    return {
        props: { story: data }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

**QUESTION**

All I want to do is click on any story link, then it takes me to the details page, via the _id. I have tried a few things but I'm doing something (or some things) wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT AFTER. ERROR I'M GETTING. I'm not able to map my results on getStaticPaths

[image]

Comment: Is the API route returning the expected data? Is the GraphQL request returning the expected response?

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const { storyId } = context.query;    // Your dynamic page is [storyId].js
    const server = "YOUR SERVER VARIABLE";

    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/${storyId}`);
      // trying to get the params._id from each story
    const { data } = await res.json();
    return {
        props: { story: data }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Devdreamsolution. I'm still having an issue with my getStaticPath map. Could you take a look? I have updated at the bottom with the picture of the error

Comment: server is not defined in your getStaticPath.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it, I have defined it as in the getStaticPath. Still getting the error map undefined.

Comment: Also, when I console.log(data) in getStaticProps, I'm getting undefined

Comment: I suggest you check your API with below
/api/entries/allStories/MANUAL_ID

Answer (score 0):

uncomment

`const router = useRouter()`
`const storyId = router.query.storyId`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sadeek - I have uncommented but i'm still getting an error on my getStaticPaths. Take a look at the error at the bottom of the question. Something about my map function

Answer (score 0):

```
// some helpful links
// https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-paths-key-required
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783199/error-getstaticpaths-is-required-for-dynamic-ssg-pages-and-is-missing-for-xxx



export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const server = "http://localhost:3000";

    const data = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/`).then(res => res.json() )

    const paths = data.map(({_id}) => ({
        params: { storyId: _id },
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}



export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {

    const storyId = context.params.storyId;    // Your dynamic page is [storyId].js
    const server = "http://localhost:3000";

    // const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/${storyId}`);
    // trying to get the params._id from each story 
    // single api call (here)
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/entries/allStories/`);
    // removing const { data } because the data will be returned when calling res.json()
    const data = await res.json();
    // instead of the calling the single api (just a fix not recommended to access [0] directly )
    return {
        props: { story: data.filter(story => story._id === storyId)[0] }
    }
}
```