# Nextjs getStaticPaths Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages . NextJS

Tags: getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

I have been trying to use getStatic props in my nextjs project, to pre-render the component for seo purpose. getStaticProps was used inside the pages and when i try to build the project it shows the following error.

"[getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for "xxx". NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783199/error-getstaticpaths-is-required-for-dynamic-ssg-pages-and-is-missing-for-xxx)"

I tried to use getStaticProps inside the pages and to load the data for seo purpose and i want to build the project, get the data via api call in the pages.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic pages or slugs, the path with expected params has to be defined in getStaticPaths.
Please refer https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths

Comment: This is for the Pages Router. How to do this with the App Router?